# Getting a displayed line from a large string

Tags: java, android

What I want to do is to measure the data of a line on a large string. I am not sure if any has tried this but I have a string which looks like this.

> String a =
>   "This is
>   kinda
>   my String"

which would display on android textview as

> This is
>   kinda
>   my String

Now what I want to achieve is being able get the **length** of the second line "kinda".

The purpose for this is to be able to set my paging for a book project.

I hope I was clear enough. Thanks for any advice or ideas shared.

Comment: Huh? What do you mean by "second line"? Anyway, if you just are after a way of getting the length of the string `a`, do `a.length();`.

Comment: Are you looking to implement some sort of a Word Wrapping algorithm? See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_wrap#Algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used java in years that being said I'd imagine something like this

```
  String[] temp; //Let's make an array of strings
  temp = a.split("\n"); //Split the large string by carriage return
  int length = temp[1].length(); //get the length of the 2nd string
```

Assuming those are \n separating your lines...

Answer (score 2):

Should just be:

```
a.split("\n")[1].length()
```

Comment: Yeah you're right, originally he had it as one line separated by spaces, edited to reflect OP's changes.

Comment: Well yes in simple terms yes but the thing though is the large sum of words and phrases. Your code only calculates after second space which is kinda.length which is correct. What I want to achieve is random paragraph. Thanks though. *Correction typed slower than what was edited of a.split(" ")[2].legnth().

Comment: And OP  wants second line, which would be index [1] not [2]

Comment: @thinksteep Yeah, forgot to change that after OP changed his string structure as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the String function [split(String regex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

To split on a "\n"(newline) then use it as a tuple/array and call for any word you want.

Answer (score 1):

Split based on new line indicator.

```
String lines[] = a.split("\\r?\\n");
int length =0;
if(lines.length >1)
{
length = lines[1].length();
}
```